# Get post from a single category with have_posts () WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am showing the last post of a blog on an external website that I am developing out of wordpress.

```
<?php
 //Include WordPress
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
 require('./blog/wp-load.php');
 //Define quantos posts serão exibidos
 query_posts('showposts=3');
?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<li>
 <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>                      
 <span><?php the_time("d/m/Y"); ?></span>
 <?php the_category_ID(); ?>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <div>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">&laquo; Leia Mais...</a>
 </div>
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

The point is that the blog is separated into two categories and I would like to display only one of them.

Link where I got those functions.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query posts, you can add the conditions for categories as well, like this:

```
 query_posts('showposts=3&cat=CAT_ID'); //replace CAT_ID with the category ID that you want
```

Since you mentioned that you wanted to show the latest posts, you might need to do this:

```
query_posts('showposts=3&cat=CAT_ID&orderby=date&order=DESC');
```

Comment: Thank you Amit. Could you tell me if there is any function that returns only the image of the post? Well, the posts will only have some image.

Comment: As you can see, I'm using the_content( ) function; And this brings the whole content of the blog, but I just wanted the image.

Comment: That would be a completely different question. However can you tell me how this image is associated with the posts in question. Are you adding them as their featured image?